# MATLAB colorbar labels cut off in printing with large images

Tags: printing, graphics, matlab

I'm using false-color visualizations for some HDR images in MATLAB, but with large images I find that the colorbar labels get cut off.

In the MWE below, colorbar labels (and I think some of the colorbar too) have been cut off when I print to PDF for inclusion in LaTeX. I've uploaded the output I'm getting [here](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~ssilk083/test.pdf).

Can anyone suggest a fix? Thanks.

MATLAB Code:

```
h=2304; w=3072;
y=(1:1:2304)';
x=1:1:3072;
z=y*x;

figure();
imshow(z,[]);
colormap(jet);
colorbar;

print(gcf, 'test.pdf', '-dpdf');
```

Comment: It works fine with Matlab R2010b on Linux. Maybe you could upload your `test.pdf` and also add a MWE example of your `.tex` file to show how you include the PDF into your document?

Comment: @Jake: thanks for the reply. I've updated my post with a link to the output file I'm getting and slightly different code just to make the file smaller; the problem is still the same. Thanks.

Comment: Try issuing `set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','Auto','PaperType','a4')` before you print the image.

Comment: @Jake: Just tried that, it didn't work. It actually cut off more stuff than before, including a big chunk of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Worked fine on 2008b here, but the bounding box is wrong for what people normally expect on an embeddable graph. MATLAB has always treated PDF export as a special case of printing to a regular printer, when it should be analogous to making an EPS.

What I normally do for LaTeX is create an EPS file, and then convert it to PDF. I wrote a `pdfprint.m` file some time back to automate that. It should work on any Windows or UNIX-like system with MATLAB and `epstopdf` (standard with LaTeX). You can download it [here](http://trac.cae.tntech.edu/ttuthesis/wiki/Tips/Figures#HowDoIExportaGraphfromMATLAB).

Also, the `pdflatex` in TeX Live 2010 can automatically convert EPS graphics to PDF when needed.